# Get user selection from my database from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need help to get specific user selection from my database after the user select an option, in this case WEIGHT, from the dropdown list which is populated from the database. I have tried the following but to no avail.

My code so far:

```
<td><select class="weight" name="weight" id="weight">
        <option>Weight of parcel</option>
        <?php
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM parcel_weight");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
            ?>
            <option><?php echo $row["weight"]; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>

</td>
</select>

<div id="submitBtn">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" 
           value="Submit"></input>
</div>  
<?php
if (isset($_POST['#submit_btn'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT weight_id FROM parcel_weight WHERE weight_id =;"
            . $_REQUEST['#weight'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row['weight_id'];
}
?>
```

Comment: FYI you are not closing `<input>` properly

Comment: using `$_REQUEST` is a bad idea

Comment: also your `sql` statement is invalid. Apart from SQL injection attacks

Comment: Do you have a <form> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what error you are getting, I can only guess you're getting an SQL error where you've terminated the statement with ';' before adding the variable.  Also, there is no need for the '#' in the _REQUEST variable.

```
$sql = "SELECT weight_id FROM parcel_weight WHERE weight_id = '".$_REQUEST['weight']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your closing `select` and `td` tags are in the wrong order (why are `td` tags here not in a table?), close the `select` and then the `td`, also you may want to add a value to each `option`.

And also, your `select` and submit `input` need to be within a form for this script to work the way you intend. Have a look at the following:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_btn'])) {
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];
    $sql = "SELECT weight_id FROM parcel_weight WHERE weight = '$weight'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row['weight_id'];
}
?>  
<form method="post" action="">
    <select class="weight" name="weight" id="weight">
        <option>Weight of parcel</option>
        <?php
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM parcel_weight");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
            $weight = $row['weight'];
            echo "<option value=\"$weight\">$weight</option>";
        } 

        ?>
        </select>
    <div id="submitBtn">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
    </div> 
</form>
```

I would highly recommend prepared statements as your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection

Answer (score 0):

Before all, you must use html form tags to get a valid form. With that, you'll need an action attribute to define where your form will go, and a method [GET] or [POST]

For more informations : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

```
<form action="#" method="GET">
 <select class="weight" name="weight" id="weight">
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

To catch your select, you have to check the $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST depending on which one you choose on the method's attribute.

You need to remove the # before the name, in your case :

```
if (isset($_POST['#weight']))
```

is :

```
if (isset($_POST['weight'])) {}
```

To finish, you have to add a value to earch option in your select :

```
<option value="<?php echo $row["weight"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["weight"]; ?></option>
```